# Building gcc by revision number

Tags: gcc, version-control, legacy

I am struggling to understand the version control system that gcc uses (not the Github mirror). Also, is there any way to get the gcc source code by revision number. Thank you.

Comment: Please consult https://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror and then, if you still have questions about how to access the source code, ask them on the mailing list `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`.  That is the best way to communicate with the people who can actually help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about a specific free software project's development practices, better asked directly of that project.